# Running Ruby on Rails app on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Aptana Studio 3 for development of ROR apps. I used run server command and it showed you can access your app on {http//0.0.0.0:3000/}, but when I try to access this URL, it tells me to check your Internet connection. I tried several other ports also but it is not working. I have created/modified the files necessary and migrated the database successfully too. Appreciate any help in running the app over the browser. I am currently using WeBrick Server.

Comment: did you try with:  `http://localhost:3000/`?

Comment: yes but its not working...

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: Took quite long for me to figure it out. It ran over http://localhost:3000/my_project_name :)

Answer (score 0):

so, in your title you say "on server". what does that mean? when you are running it on a different machine than your own, you need to use the address of that machine or it's domain name. keep in mind that firewall rules might prevent any connection to that server.

when you are ON the machine, via ssh for example, you can try calling the then "local" rails instance with `curl http://localhost:3000/` to verify that it is running.

Comment: Thanks phoet! Just now I have ran it on http://localhost:3000/my_project_name and it is running fine. Everytime I have to run the server with rails server and then I can access it over the above url. Once again, thanks for the reply!